# calculating and displaying time in c

Tags: c

I'm just learning C and I have a lesson that starts with a certain time, I have to add a certain additional amount of time, then display the new time.  I've gotten it to add the minutes, but my result shows as it I'm adding numbers.

Example is I start at `640` then want to add `30` minutes, but it displays as `670`, but I need it to display as `710`.  I would like hint/tips and not the actual programming as I'd like to try to figure on my own at this point. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing a time as an integer.  That's my first hint.

Comment: Don't store as single number, don't calculate as single number.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show the [mcve] which does the 640+30=670 calculation and output.

Comment: As for your problem, the standard unit of time on almost all systems is the number of seconds since 00:00:00 January 1 1970. If you use that as a base, then you can use all [the standard C time functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono).

Comment: @TrippKinetics Time as an integer is fine if one uses a small enough quata like maybe a [chronon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronon)  ;-).

Comment: When trying to print, consider using an array to store times: `int tim[3]` where `0 is secs`, `1 is mins` and `2 is hours`. Then, treat `tim` like you would if you were doing addition on paper (e.g. carry out from one column to another). That is base 10, but here you've got base 60. Now, how would you fill `tim` from your mins value? And, then, how would you print `tim`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply a *decimal* math operation on two *decimal* values that are *not decimals*. They are some type of "hour:minutes" units, printed without a ':' character in between. C does not know that, so it doesn't automatically overflow the minutes when you add `1` to `659` and expected to get `700`. Instead, you get `660`, which – if this "time" unit *was* a valid integer type – would be an *invalid* value! The "minutes" part would only allow `00` up to `59`.

You can compare this to octal numbers. `77` is a valid octal number, with an actual *decimal* value of `63` (in decimals). Adding `1` to it and printing it again would yield `100` (in octal), not `78`.

As C cannot detect minute overflows when counting with your made-up units, the proper route to follow is to convert the input to "regular" decimals, do any calculation you want, then convert back to "time" decimals. You can do that with basic modulus and division arithmetic – "time format" to a proper decimal value is easy, so start with that. Then apply the same logic to convert back from decimal to time.

Of course this will break when you try to feed it "invalid" values such as `670` (invalid, as `70` cannot indicate minutes) or `2510` (I left out proper around-the-clock 24h calculations – add this if you need it). Other than with octal numbers, your compiler will not be able to point out erroneous values.

Actual code below, hidden by a spoiler tag. Reveal at your own risk.

> In case you *immediately* moused over it: ...I am disappointed. The code is comprehensive and short, that longish explanation above took about four times as long to write.
>
> ```
>   #include <stdio.h>
>
>
>   #define NUMTOMINUTES(x) 100*((x)/60)+((x) % 60)
>   #define MINUTESTONUM(x) (((x) % 100)+60*((x)/100))
>
>
>   int main (void)
>   {
>     int time_a, time_add, time_b;
>
>
>     time_a = 630;
>     time_add = 40;
>     time_b = MINUTESTONUM(time_a) + MINUTESTONUM(time_add);
>
>
>     printf ("time_a is %d\n", time_a);
>     printf ("time_b is %d\n", NUMTOMINUTES(time_b));
>
>
>     return 0;
>   }
> ```

This works properly even if you do `630 + 110`; it adds up as `06:30 + 01:10`, leading to a correct result of `740`.

Comment: I'm not sure the spoiler tag thing isn't more a "cutsie" than helpful... But the effort is commendable.